# Deleting archived products - Will the products inside orders be affected?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, orders

I have a lot of archived products that I would like to delete.

But I am using a function in the frontend where users can see their old orders and what products were bought:

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')
     ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $storeId)
     ->load();
```

Some of these products are already archived.

When I delete all archived products, can the products inside the orders still be accessed? Or will I lose those products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the orders don't have only references to the order products, but they also keep product values (that might seam redundant) because you want to see a snapshot of the product you ordered at the time you ordered it.
This way you avoid seeing new prices or descriptions.
The order history section that magento offers by default works even if you delete ordered products.
but if you have a custom code that loads a product collection or a product to get additional info, it will be affected if you delete the products.

If the only code you use is the one you shown in the question you should be save.
I suggest trying to delete the products first on a staging server then do it on live.
and backup before doing anything.

Comment: Not all the attributes of the product are saved in the order. Check the sales_order_item table columns to see what is saved